# Select or create a view of last 3 articles from more than 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, top-n

I have two tables. One has articles (`article`), what are static pages on website. Second has blog articles (`blog_article`), which articles are shown just in the blog page.

Now I want to show latest articles order by `date` on my homepage. It is easy to show last 3 from `article` or `blog_article`, but I have problem to do it from both at once.

Both tables have same structure, except for `article`, where I want to get rows only with `cat_id = 3`.

This is `article`:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| id | name      | content       | date      | cat_id      |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Test 1    | ...           | 2016-01-24 18:26:00 | 3 |
| 2  | Test 2    | ...           | 2016-01-29 18:26:00 | 3 |
| 3  | Test 3    | ...           | 2016-02-07 18:26:00 | 4 |
| 4  | Test 4    | ...           | 2016-02-18 18:26:00 | 1 |
| 5  | Test 5    | ...           | 2016-03-15 18:26:00 | 3 |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

This is `blog_article`:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| id | name      | content       | date                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Blog 1    | ...           | 2016-03-01 18:26:00     |
| 2  | Blog 2    | ...           | 2016-03-10 18:26:00     |
| 3  | Blog 3    | ...           | 2016-04-08 18:26:00     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I expect to return:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| id | name      | content       | date                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Blog 3    | ...           | 2016-04-08 18:26:00     |
| 2  | Test 5    | ...           | 2016-03-15 18:26:00     |
| 3  | Blog 2    | ...           | 2016-03-10 18:26:00     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I tried this command

```
SELECT article.name AS name, blog_article.name AS name
FROM article,
     blog_article
WHERE article.cat_id = 3
ORDER BY article.date DESC
LIMIT 3
```

but no help. I'm not really good in SQL, I use only `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`... basic commands.

Or create a view, but still, no success with command above.

Comment: Search for `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Also, your join has no join condition! Skip that old, implicit, comma separated join syntax, use only modern, explicit `join` syntax!

Comment: @FelixPamittan thanks I think I have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea using `order by` and `limit` but a wrong one with the (implicit) join. Logically, you'd want to treat articles and blog articles the same, meaning you need to `union all` between them:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     (SELECT name, date FROM article WHERE cat_id = 3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT name, date FROM blog_article) t
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the MySQL's [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) statement

```
SELECT name FROM 
    ( ( SELECT article.name AS name, `date` FROM article WHERE article.cat_id = 3 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 3 )   
    UNION ALL     
    ( SELECT name AS name, `date` FROM blog_article WHERE ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 3 ) ) unified    
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: 13000 points, and giving a answer that should have been a comment. (That was given minutes ago.)

Comment: really, you took your time to bash my first version of the answer instead of answering the question yourself?

Comment: Well, at least I didn't downvote. Seriously, that first version wasn't much of an answer, and also more and less the same as  Felix Pamittan's already existing comment.

Comment: @jarlh  The user has wrote an answer. If the answer solve the problem  and return the expected result, it's fine. If you have something to add you wrote another answer or you edit... What's the point if he has 13000 point or 1 point? what's your frustration?

Comment: As extra info , it had the link to the UNION. Also, the first version was more intended to signal other people that this question has an answer (in progress) so that they can focus on helping others

Comment: Alright, I get the "work in progress" point. No reason to argue. Have a nice day, all of you!